# getting div to float right and align bottom of variable div

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to create a template for some rotating spotlights we create here at work, and what I'm trying to do should be rather simple.

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aeromax/2t4k4cf9/

What I'm trying to do, is to get #spotlightCTA to float right (easily doable) and align to the bottom of the #spotlightTitle, so that the call to action moves up or down depending on how tall the title is.

Here is the styles associated with these two divs:

```
#spotlightTitle {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    bottom: 0px;
}

#spotlightCTA {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    right: 0px;
    float: right;
}
```

And my HTML

```
<div id="spotlightContent">
    <div id="spotlightTitle">
        <div class="title">This is a test title.<br>Let's make it longer.
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="spotlightCTA" class="animate">
        <span>This is a call to action.</span>
        <button type="">Test button</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

If I float right, it aligns to the top. If I remove the float, it aligns to the bottom but I can't get it to align to the right.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove the floats and give both `<div>`  `vertical-align:bottom;`- http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/2t4k4cf9/5/ (Adjust your needs)

Comment: Can't you just use position: absolute ? http://jsfiddle.net/2t4k4cf9/6/

Comment: I was trying that, but it was positioning itself in relation to the highest parent div, and not it's immediate parent div, all of which were not explicitly positioned (static). I didn't realize all the parent divs had to be positioned relatively, so once I did that it worked by just using bottom: 0px and float: right.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
div {
  background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, .2);
}
/*Containers*/

#spotlightContainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 646px;
  padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}
#spotlightContent {
  width: 646px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
#spotlightTitle {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 0px;
}
/*CTA*/

#spotlightCTA {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 0px;
  float: right;
}
#spotlightCTA span {
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#spotlightCTA button {
  background-color: #ffd200;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: none;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
.title {
  font-family: "Oswald", "Helvetica Neue", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  max-width: 400px;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="spotlightContainer">

  <div id="spotlightContent">
    <div id="spotlightTitle">
      <div class="title">This is a test title.
        <br>Let's make it longer.
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="spotlightCTA" class="animate">
      <span>This is a call to action.</span>
      <button type="">Test button</button>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to keep this compliant for older browsers unfortunately, as our target audience (finance) is still relatively low tech. Is there a way to make flex box fall back?

Comment: `position:absolute` if you want rock-solid fallback...but this will override flexbox anyway.